# Cancelling a preference change

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to cancel a preference change before it is actually performed?

The preference changed listener only lets me see the change but does not let me cancel it.
In certain cases I need to show an AlertDialog to the user to allow him to maybe cancel the change.
Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: If you return `false` from preference changed listener it should not apply the new value..

Comment: @denis I don't think so, the [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) returns void.

Comment: @Patrick sorry, I thought you were talking about regular `Preferences` like in `PreferenceActivity`, not SharedPreferences`...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can control the change, as it is only stored after you call the commit function

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("somevalue", true);
editor.commit();
```

You can preview the value with a toast or something before you call commit. or a yes/no dialog.